# Matlab read text file to cell array

Tags: matlab, text, cell-array

I want to read some data from a text file but I don't know how to do this.
I know that I can read text files like this

```
fid=fopen('data.txt');
A = textscan(fid,'%s')
```

which returns

```
A =
{
  [1,1] =
  {
    [1,1] = drink
    [2,1] = water
    [3,1] = drink
    [4,1] = eat
    [5,1] = drink
    [6,1] = spoon
    [7,1] = water
    [8,1] = drink
    [9,1] = water
    [10,1] = drink
  }
}
```

the text file looks like this

```
drink water drink
eat drink spoon
water drink water drink
```

But I want to store the data in a cell array like this

```
A =
{
  [1,1] =
  {
    [1,1] = drink
    [1,2] = water
    [1,3] = drink
  }
  [1,2] =
  {
    [1,1] = eat
    [1,2] = drink
    [1,3] = spoon
  }
  [1,3] =
  {
    [1,1] = water
    [1,2] = drink
    [1,3] = water
    [1,4] = drink
  }
}
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Double check the expected output?

Comment: What do you mean wirh double check the output?

Comment: `A[1,1]` has three `drink` cells and I am assuming [1,1] corresponds to the first row of the text file that has only two `drink`

Comment: We are in super hurry, aren't we? Double check again?

Comment: A[1,3] feels neglected too. Reminds me I need some drink too, and by that I mean just water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `importdata` and `regexp` with `'Split'` option -

```
out = cellfun(@(x) regexp(x,'\s','Split'),importdata(text_filename,'\n'),'un',0).'
```

Output -

```
out{1,1}
ans = 
    'drink'    'water'    'drink'
out{1,2}
ans = 
    'eat'    'drink'    'spoon'
out{1,3}
ans = 
    'water'    'drink'    'water'    'drink'
```

Comment: thanks but this doesn't really work. Im fairly new to matlab. I tried your solution an got an error: 'un' syntax error. Could you please explain me what this 'un' means

Comment: @user2348157 Try replacing that `'un'` with `'UniformOutput'` and let me know how it goes? That `'un'` is like a short-hand for that.

Comment: @user2348157 For more info on that, please refer to the official doc page - http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html

Comment: After replacing it i didn't get the error. But I get this now cellfun: C must be a cell array. I am not sure if I understand this right. Instead of using A=textscan... I use the code you posted and I should get the cell array?

Comment: @user2348157 Did you edit `text_filename` with the path to the text file? You are supposed to do that. So, it would be - `out = cellfun(@(x) regexp(x,'\s','Split'),importdata('data1.txt','\n'),'un',0).'`, if `data1.txt` is the name of the text file in the working directory.

Comment: yes I changed text_filename to data.txt. Im not using Matlab I'm using Octave.

Comment: @user2348157 So let's suppose you do - `text_data = importdata(text_filename,'\n')`, what do you see in `text_data` and what's the class of `text_data`, is it a cell array?

Comment: @user2348157 So, then `out = cellfun(@(x) regexp(x,'\s','Split'),text_data,'UniformOutput',false).'` must work I would hope.

Comment: got the same error again error: cellfun: C must be a cell array

Comment: @user2348157 If you are feeding it `text_data`, why is it complaining about C. Not sure what's going on there. Are you using some variable named `C` somewhere?

Comment: no I did  text_data = importdata('data.txt'); and out = cellfun(@(x) regexp(x,'\s','Split'),text_data,'UniformOutput',false).'

Comment: @user2348157 Could be a octave specific thing, don't have that to test it out.

Comment: @user2348157 Sorry, I still don't have resources to test that out. Did you manage to solve it?